# Достать число из изображения

Tags: java, img, распознавание-образов

Нужно достать из картинки число. Нашёл что то про javaOCR и если правильно понял , то нужно платить. Если ли аналоги?
Вот пример картинки с которой нужно будет работать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А руками написать не годится? Это ж не капча даже.

http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?p=6778307#p6778307

Подготовительная часть:

1. Определяем эталонный размер символа
   Этот размер представляет некий bounding box символа и должен быть адекватным большинству символов
2. Для каждого символа делаем его эталонную картинку (символ чёрный, фон белый, других цветов нет)
   Картинка должна быть эталонного размера, причём он должен представлять bounding box для области символа
   Если это не так, то масштабируем (обеспечив наличие ровно двух цветов в результате)
3. В памяти эталонную картинку храним в виде двумерного массива boolean'ов

Обработка картинки:

1. Берём картинку (цветную), из неё (любым доступным способом) получаем массив цветов пикселей (двумерный).
2. Находим связные тёмные области
3. Для каждой такой области выделяем её в отдельную картинку, смасштабированную до эталонного размера
4. Сравниваем получившийся массив с каждым из эталонных (проверкой, что ЦветПикселяТёмный(X,Y) = Шаблон(I)(X,Y)), определяем число несоответствий
5. Выбираем тот символ, для которого число несоответствий минимально

Comment: Спасибо. Я так понимаю получится что то вроде не обучаемой нейросети).И тут сразу такой вопрос, если ли на java хорошие примеры нейросетей?

Comment: @МихаилКетов, нет, это не нейросеть. Это самый простейший алгоритм сравнения с образцом, когда известен шрифт. Только я внёс небольшое изменение: масштабирование символа под эталонный размер. Ну и упрощение, что символ - это связная область. Для некоторых символов это не так: `Ыыiё=?!:;%`, но они у тебя вроде не встречаются. Я этот способ даже для распознавания капчи использовал - очень даже успешно. Ну там ещё предварительная очистка от шума выполнялась, а потом прям по приведённой схеме. Про нейронные сети не в курсе.