# Как написать программу на C# для поиска дубликатов изображений?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

На входе много изображений, а на выходе определяет дубликат среди этих многих изображений

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/445159/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy Уточните, что это за ссылка и как она относится к этому вопросу?

Comment: В вопросе недостаточно информации. Попиксельное совпадение или примерное? Насколкьо разные картинки должны определяться как дубликаты - размер, поворот, фрагменты, другие искажения?

Answer (score 4):

Предполагается, что речь идёт именно о дубликатах, т. е. о попиксельном совпадении.

## Способ 1:

1. Группируем картинки по размеру (в пикселях)
2. Выбираем рандомные координаты пикселя и группируем картинки по его цвету
3. Повторяем пункт 1 в каждой группе до получения достаточно мелких групп
4. В мелких группах сравниваем картинки попарно попиксельно

## Способ 2:

1. Группируем картинки по размеру (в пикселях).
2. Получаем из картинок массив rgba-пикселей
3. Строим префиксное дерево (или как там оно называется), добавив в начало размеры
4. Если последовательность заканчивается в том же листе, значит картинки совпадают

Comment: Не плохие варианты, рекомендую сделать пред сравнение. Эти алгоритмы будут хороши при должной реализации но все равно трудо затратные. Перед их запуском сравните картинки по хэш суммам хотя бы.

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V, мне не кажется, что подсчёт хэшей даст выигрыш. Или имеется в виду хэш файла? Тогда это не то, поскольку мои способы предполагают, что одинаковые картинки в разных форматах (или с разными метаданными) - это всё же дубликаты, если попиксельно они совпадают, а хеши файлов раскидают их в разные группы.

Answer (score 1):

Если картинки не точные дубликаты, а разного размера, немного отличающегося цвета, то можно делать хэши изображений. В самом простом варианте так:

1. Сжать все изображения до размера 16*16.
2. Обесцветить полученные картинки до состояний пикселей 0 и 1.
3. Найти расстояние Хемминга между образцом и всеми проверяемыми значениями. Поделить полученные значения на 256, вычесть их из единицы и умножить на сто — получите процент схожести.

Реализуется это довольно легко, для большинства простых задач работает как надо.

Answer (score 1):

Для случая когда интересует попиксельное совпадение.
Получаем картинку в формате RGBA, переводим в массив байт, считаем контрольную сумму -- хэш SHA1 например. Одинаковые картинки будут с одинаковым хэшем, разные с разным -- вероятность совпадения разных картинок настолько мала, что ей можно пренебречь.