# Сравнение двух одинаковых изображений

Tags: c#, обработка-изображений, распознавание-образов

Всем добрый вечер.
Есть 2 одинаковых фотографии с некоторым объектом. Одна фотография обработана системой обнаружения образов, другая обработана человеком. На обеих фотографиях вокруг объекта наблюдения присутствует рамка, обозначающая выделение объекта.
Стоит задача определить эффективность обнаружения объекта системой. Есть мысли искать на 'сцене' прямоугольник и далее сравнивать координаты.
Если есть другой способ сравнить эффективность обнаружения, буду очень признателен за совет. Также буду очень признателен, если порекомендуете библиотеку, которая сможет задетектить конкретную фигуру не на однотонном фоне, а на фотографии. Заранее спасибо. Пишу на с#.

Comment: Рамка прямоугольная? А смысл был её на картинке рисовать?

Comment: @Qwertiy рамка прямоугольная. Глобальная задача стоит в определении эффективности системы обнаружения образов. Система обнаружила на сцене аномалию и пометила ее. Человек, обрабатывая тот же кадр тоже пометил ее. Нужно определить насколько точно система обнаружения пометила этот объект. Система обнаружения может быть любой, главное, чтобы размечала кадры

Comment: Ну так пусть в координатах сразу выдаёт результат четырьмя числами. Это же тупо сначала рисовать на картинке, потом распознавать нарисованное. Хотя прямоугольник фиксированного цвета найти и несложно. Ну и человек бы в проге просто выделил, а она координаты сохранила.

Comment: @Qwertiy в том то и дело, что мы не можем получить координаты от системы. Мы тестируем черный ящик. И человек должен выделять тоже просто рамкой, без сохранения координат. Мы имеем 2 изображения с рамками и полное отсутствие дескрипторов этих изображений

Comment: Ну значит ищем рамку, получаем координаты, сравниваем.

Comment: @Qwertiy может посоветуете библиотеку на .net? emgy/forge?

Comment: Знаешь, я б руками написал минут за 15, чем какую-то библиотеку искать. Это ж одноцветный прямоугольник без прозрачности? Хм.. Даже если с прозрачностью, можно сравнить обе картинки и получить разницу, только там ещё фигуру надо будет разделить на два прямоугольника.

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо! попробую сотворить что-нибудь.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/812762/184217