# Как сравнить на сходство два изображения? Распознавание-символов/образов в C#

Tags: c#, искусственный-интеллект, распознавание-символов, распознавание, распознавание-образов

Есть задача определить масть игральной карты. Есть ли готовое решение, функция, которая позволит в процентом соотношении понять на сколько изображение похоже и выбрать наиболее подходящее к эталону? Решение нужно реализовать на C#.

Возможно можно использовать какую-то библиотеку по распознаванию текста и распознать масти как символы юникода?

Изображения на входе могут иметь разный угол наклона и не всегда ровно в центре картинка масти

На входе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
или
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и т.д.

Эталонные изображения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Emgu.CV есть и Tesseract для текста. Можно найти готовые нейронки или самому натренировать.

Comment: [посмотрите тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/812394/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8/812762#812762)

Comment: Бинаризируй, выделяй знак масти.  Находи выпуклую оболочку.  Находи разницу между оболочкой и символов. Если число компонентов разницы - 1 то это черви, 2 пики и т.д.  Этот способ не зависит от поворотов и небольших перспективных искажений.