# как распознать на картинке цифры?

Tags: php, распознавание-символов

Как определить координаты пикселей на которых изображены цифры?
[image: картинка]

[image: img]

Хочу перевести изображения в текст, собираюсь пользоваться массивами с шаблонами цифр для распознавания. Не могу придумать как распознать позиции на которых расположены символы. в разных изображениях они в разных местах, в некоторых под наклоном

Comment: Это не тривиальная задача решается методами распознавания образо. Можно использовать сторонние библотеки, а можно и самому нечто похожее на нейросети забабахать, первый способ быстрый но несильно гибкий, второй гибкий но не сильно быстрый.

Есть какието требования у Вас, которые смогут выбрать варианты?

Comment: Мало примеров. А вообще, легко: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/429136/178988 & http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/445172/178988

Comment: @Zugr, при том, что у него сейчас на картинке, всё решается гораздо проще, чем ты описал.

Comment: на всех изображениях только цифры в количестве 16 штук

Comment: Ну вот. Я же не описывал решения, я уточнения спросил!

Comment: @Zugr, Гибкость мне ни к чему, решение собираюсь использовать только в одном месте

Comment: Вторая картинка значительно хуже первой, потребуется дополнительная логика для разделения соседних цифр. Как вариант, проверять четырёхсвязные области, а красное и жёлтое сразу удалять. А ещё удалять столбцы, в которых только одна точка.

Comment: Он имел в виду гибкость в плане подгонки решения под твою задачу.

Comment: @Qwertiy, подскажи пожалуйста как мне средствами php определить связанную область черных пикселов?

Comment: @user193361, про средства php понятия не имею, а вообще, стандартный алгоритм заливки с затравкой.

Comment: http://opencv.org / https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract / https://github.com/tmbdev/ocropy

Answer (score -1):

```
Есть готовые программы, которые позволяют распознать текст не просто
для чтения, но и для манипулирования этими данными.
Например Кибор.
Он имеет гибкий язык программирования, а так же встроенную функцию распознавания текста.
Ниже на скриншотах показан процесс настройки и использования в программе функции распознавания текста за четыре действия.
Потом с этими распознанными данными можно делать что надо.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Подробнее о распознавание текста в Кибор](http://kibor-bot.com/stat/read_text.php)

Comment: Причем тут программы, вы метки смотрите, прежде чем писать свой удручающий ответ?